How to calculate attributions in a log-log model
Let's say I have a time-series oriented log-log model of the form ln(y) = B0 + B1ln(x1) + B2ln(x2). Let's say B0=1.5, B1=0.7, and B2=0.9. I use my model to make two predictions at different time periods. At time period 1, let's say x1=10 and x2=20 and so ŷ1=exp(1.5+0.7ln(10)+0.9ln(20))=332.94. At time period 2, x1=12 and x2=25 and so ŷ2=exp(1.5+0.7ln(12)+0.9ln(25))=462.38.
Now I want to attribute the difference between the predicted outcome from the two time periods to x1 and x2. For example, I want to be able to say of the 129.44 difference in ŷ, 68.24 of it was attributable to changes in x1 and the remaining 61.20 was attributable to changes in x2 (hypothetical here, of course). How can I calculate this?

(1) What does this have to do with time series? (2) You can't partition the influence of the variables unless the variables are orthogonal.  What you're asking is mathematically identical to asking how much of one side of a triangle can be additively attributed to each of the lengths of the other two sides.  That can be done only for right triangles (according to the Pythagorean Theorem).


Just ignore the time series issue for now. 2) Assume the variables are orthogonal. For example, if we had a straight linear model y=B0+B1x1+B2x2, with the same coefficients, x1, and x2 values as above, the attributions would be straightforward. ŷ1 would be 26.5 and ŷ2 would be 32.4. The difference attributable to x1 would be B2(12-10)=1.4 and to x2 would likewise be 4.5. These sum up to the difference between ŷ2 and ŷ1. This is what I'd like to be able to do with the log-log model.


There's nothing left to say: when the variables are orthogonal, just read the contributions off the coefficient estimates.  The logarithms are a red herring, because they're merely another way of numerically expressing values of the explanatory variables.  They have no effect at all on the question or its solution.
